# Where to store custom list of values in Magento

Tags: magento

I am writing an extension in Magento that will import files. I want to keep a list of these files in the database somewhere so that I know not to process them again.
Is there any built in functionality that I can hijack to keep a list?

If not, how would I go about creating a new table to hold these values?
I was thinking of simply using `Mage_Core_Model_Config` and storing the values in there, however it probably isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a datatable that stores them. additionnaly, you will need to create the according model and define them in a config.xml under a ressource tag.

if you just need to store a value, you can do it in the core_config_data.